# Automatic transfer to ftp after any file is modified

Tags: windows, netbeans, ftp

Is there a Windows option, FileZilla option, other FTP program or some other program I can use that will copy any file I modify in a directory to a directory in an FTP Server?

Situation: I'm doing my development in my machine with my own server, but since it can't be broadcast, I have it serving from another domain.  I'm in the beginning stages so code is changed every minute, but it is tiresome to copy the modified files to the FTP every time and also remember the ones that need to be copied.

So, I want a program that will check my directory and upload any modified files to the FTP.

Comment: There are several text editors that can modify files directly over FTP. Perhaps that's a solution for you?

Comment: Some FTP clients support auto-uploading of changed files.  Fling, for instance.  I've never used it but I think it would work.

Comment: Remembering the modified ones should be as simple as sorting the directory by last-modified-time, unless you're working in multiple subdirectories.

Comment: Yes, there are many subdirectories.    I'll look into Fling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans has its own "Project from a Remote Server". And it will auto sync any changed file!

Tested and worked.

Thanks to Mikecito for the suggestion.